# How do I create a SUSE 10 Docker Image?

Tags: docker, suse, sles

SUSE 10 SP 3 is unsupported on Docker and my goal is to create a custom image out of a SUSE 10 SP 3 iso file.

I have tried installing the iso into a VirtualBox VM and creating a tar archive, but as the OS itself is unsupported by Docker, I cannot use the docker import command and pass the tar file.

I have also tried using xorriso in an Ubuntu container, but I am having trouble running docker inside the Ubuntu container in order to use the docker import command.

Comment: Is there an in-place upgrade path from SP2 to SP3? Could you fork the SP2 image and manually run the upgrade to SP3?

Comment: As I am aware no parent docker image exists for any version of SUSE 10.